# What settings do I need to upload a big amount of images? (php.ini)

Tags: php, apache, php-ini

I'm running a website which has a gallery. I want to add a function, which allows the user of the website to add a big amount of images (up to ~300). Because there are only a few users, which should be able to upload images, I'm currently helping them out by uploading them via FTP.

I've already implemented the function in PHP and it works on localhost, but because it's on localhost, it's "uploading" the images very fast and i have no real way to test, what happens, when you upload the images to a real webserver. (Internet connection to slow, timeout?)

Some settings in the php.ini are capped by my provider (`max_execution_time`, `max_input_time`, `max_input_vars`, `memory_limit`)

Is there a good way to handle this?

- Webserver: Apache
- PHP version: 5.5+

Answer (score 0):

Other than those you may want to look at `post_max_size` and `upload_max_filesize` settings too to increase the file upload limit.

Comment: What happens, if the upload takes to long? Does that matter, if these settings are set to the right value? I've also found `max_file_uploads`

Comment: To make sure nothing happens if a file takes too long to be uploaded use `max_execution_time` as you mentioned. `max_file_uploads` is used to limit the number of files that can be sent in one request, for example if you use a file input with `multiple` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

PHP has several configuration options to limit resources consumed by scripts. By default, PHP is set to allow uploads of files with a size of 2MB or less.

Try increasing the following values in php.ini, for example:

```
memory_limit = 32M
upload_max_filesize = 24M
post_max_size = 32M
```